# How to make tcolorbox find right paths of styles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tikz-styles

I define my options of `tcolorbox` with different paths by `\tcbset`(Please see the following code).

I'd like to know how to make tcolorbox find the right path of an option?
I know that I can invoke a option with its real path. But this is boring because you have to give the path every time. Is there a way to tell tcolorbox all the related paths in advance, then every option can be used directily with its name without path?

**CODE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}

    \begin{document}
    \tcbset{/tcb/toca/.cd,
      columns/.code=\def\toccolumns{#1},
    }
    \tcbset{/tcb/tocb/.cd,
      abstract/.code=\def\tocabstract{#1}
    }
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      colback=black!30,
      /tcb/toca/columns=1,% This is right
      abstract={some text}, % This is a wrong way because path is not given.
      ]
      something
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible strategy is to use `.search also` handler to indicate that if some (non fully qualified) key is missing in the default `/tcb` path, pgf should search in other paths.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}


\tcbset{
  /toca/columns/.code=\def\toccolumns{#1},
  /tocb/abstract/.code=\def\tocabstract{#1},
  /tcb/.search also={/toca, /tocb},
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=red!21,
    /toca/columns=1,% This is a fully qualified key
    abstract={some text}, % This key is missing in /tcb/, so we search in /toca and /tocb
    ]
    something
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** If you use `/tcb/toca` and `/tcb/tocb` in place of `/toca` and `/tocb` an infinite lookup will occur (with the default handlers).

Comment: If both `/toca` and `/tocb` have a option with the same name, `columns` for example, which one will be in use when invoke `columns=2`?

Comment: @lyl the one that is in the first path in `.search also`. In this case `/toca/columns`.